# Lasso Regression R - X Fold1: internal: ... : object 'eval_safely' not found

Tags: r, prediction, lasso-regression

I am trying to do a lasso regression. It worked previously in my R environment, yet now I get a the error: x Fold1: internal: Error in mapply(FUN = eval_safely, calls, names(calls), SIMPLIFY = FALSE, : object 'eval_safely' not found

```
# Create a recipe
lr_mod_recipe <- recipe(Lead_week ~ .,
                        data = Data_train) %>%
                        step_normalize(MeterDistance) %>%
                        step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes())
```

```
# Specify the model
lasso_lr <- linear_reg(penalty = tune(), mixture = 1) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")
# mixture = 1 is lasso, mixture = 0 is ridge
```

```
# Create a workflow
lr_mod_workflow <-  workflow() %>%
  add_model(lasso_lr) %>%
  add_recipe(lr_mod_recipe) 
lr_mod_workflow
```

```
# Set tuning grid
grid_lasso <- tibble(penalty = 10^(seq(from = -3, to = 1, length.out = 100)))
grid_lasso
```

```
lasso_tune <- lr_mod_workflow %>%
  tune_grid(resamples = cv_folds,
            grid = grid_lasso,
            metrics = class_metrics)
```

I get this error after trying to excute my last chunk. I do not know what the issue is, and i'm even more surprised that my lasso regression worked previously, but I doesn't work now as of this error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these packages but it seems eval_safely is a function present in yardstick package, have you tried (re)installing it ? `install.packages("yardstick")`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! unfortunately reinstalling the yardstick package did not work.